# Use template from dependent type

Tags: c++, dependent-type, template-templates

How to call a template with a template parameter, when the template is inside a template type parameter:

```
template<template<class> class Template, class T>
struct MakeType
{
    using type = Template<T>;
};

template<class Policy>
struct Blah
{
    using type = MakeType< /*A non-instantiated template member in Policy*/, int>::type;
};
```

For example, `Policy` could have a template member `ArrayType`:

```
class ExamplePolicy
{
    template<class T>
    using ArrayType = std::vector<T>;
};
```

How do I call `MakeType` from Blah with the template `Policy::ArrayType` as `Template`.

Calling `MakeType` directly works well:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::vector<int>, MakeType<std::vector, int>::type>);
```

Would compile

Comment: Did you try `MakeType<Policy::ArrayType, int>`?

Comment: to refer to a type member of a template parameter, use 'typename Policy:: ArrayType' [-fpermissive]

     using type = MakeType<Policy::ArrayType, int>::type;

Which obviously does not work, because it is not a type. This gives type/value mismatch error for argument 1.

Comment: Okay, use `MakeType<typename Policy::ArrayType, int>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
// -*- compile-command: "g++ SO.cpp"; -*-
#include <vector>

template <template <class> class Template, class T>
struct MakeType
{
  using type = Template<T>;
};

template <class Policy>
struct Blah
{
  using type = typename MakeType<Policy::template ArrayType, int>::type;

  type foo()
  {
    return type();
  }
};

struct ExamplePolicy
{
  template <class T>
  using ArrayType = std::vector<T>;
};

int main()
{
  Blah<ExamplePolicy> blah;

  auto tmp = blah.foo();
}
```

Comment: I was too focused on passing the template template right, so I forgot the typename before the dependent type.

Comment: @user877329 no problem, I understand